# Failed to setup local dir in Hadoop on Windows

Tags: java, hadoop

Trying to run MapReduce jobs on Windows, when I got an error like this:

```
Error: Application application_1441785420720_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1441785420720_0002_000002 exited with exitCode:-1000

Diagnostics:
Application application_1441785420720_0003 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1441785420720_0003_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000 For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://HOST:8088/cluster/app/application_1441785420720_0003 Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.

Diagnostics: Failed to setup local dir /tmp/hadoop-USER/nm-local-dir, which was marked as good. Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Everything worked fine yesterday, and nothing about the Java Environment, file permissions, or Hadoop configurations has changed.

Comment: if you are using organization domain pc/laptop please connect with VPN to solve issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug related to how Hadoop 2.7 understands file permissions on Windows when you have an office domain and are not currently connected to it (e.g., because you're working remote).

The long-term fix is to upgrade to Hadoop 2.8+.

The short-term fix is to VPN into your office when working remote so that you can be connected to your office domain and Hadoop will somehow understand your permissions correctly.

Comment: I just couldn't believe that this would possibly be the fix, but VPNing in fixed it for me too! goodness!

Answer (score 7):

You should run CMD with "Run as Administrator" to fix this as the Hadoop cluster environment is on WINDOWS operating system

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: This also isn't the solution. Running as administrator does not fix the issue. See other correct answers - upgrade to Hadoop 2.8 for the bugfix, or try VPNing in to your domain, if you're working remote and you have one.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to the problem is to run the command prompt as administrator and then running the scripts like "start-all.cmd". I think the administrator privileges will solve the problem.

Comment: As already mentioned, this is not a solution, unfortunately. This is a Hadoop bug, not a Windows permissions issue. Upgrading to Hadoop 2.8+ is the easy fix.

Comment: Yes dude, running cmd as administrator worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in Hadoop 2.7 related to file permissions on windows. You can either fix the bug by [editing the code directly](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-yarn-issues/201602.mbox/%3CJIRA.12771411.1422646436000.276347.1454420139878@Atlassian.JIRA%3E) or save yourself the headache by upgrading to Hadoop 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue. Sometime back I too got this error while trying to submit the a mapreduce job. The OS was CentOS and not Windows. But however, the cause of this error is same. The /tmp directory has been created by "hdfs" user and belongs to "supergroup". It some user who does not belong to supergroup try to submit a job, the user is sure to get this error.

```
Name    User    Group       

tmp     hdfs    supergroup
```

This is the reason why when you login to your office domain and submit the job, the job executes.

Comment: I definitely agree that it's related to a permissions issue, but I'm not convinced the permissions were incorrect. In fact, as troubleshooting steps, I made sure I took ownership of the `tmp` directory, and even granted full control of the directory to `Everyone` in Windows. Even with full control granted to `Everyone`, Hadoop would throw the error, which makes me think it's a bug in how Hadoop checks permissions, rather than an actual problem with the permissions...